# Google Document Viewer shows "No Preview Available" in php

Tags: php, google-document-viewer

For some reason with the following embed code:

```
    https://docs.google.com/gview?url=<?php echo $url;?>&embedded=true
```

I have been getting a no preview available. It was working, and now it doesn't seem to.

Is there a good alternative where I can view PDF and Office files?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much looking, I found a solution, I used the standard PDF viewer with an iframe.

Answer (score 2):

You may have an old version of the viewer URL format.  Here's a different link format that's documented in [a GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/tzmartin/1cf85dc3d975f94cfddc04bc0dd399be).

```
https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true
```

If you want to embed it within a page, you can use an iframe.

```html
<iframe src="https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/papers/google.pdf&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Well, I tried that and it wasn't working for me as well..

Comment: Strange!  Could you give an example PDF for which this doesn't work?  I'd like to test it on my machine

Comment: I would, but it is an internal document, plus I did find a solution.